# Passing model parameters to handlebars template during onRender in Marionette ItemView

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

I have a handlebars template like

```
<select accesskey="z" class="timezone">
    {{#each timezones}}
    <option value="{{@key}}">{{this}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

and the corresponding portion of Marionette.ItemView like :

```
var TimeView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template : TimeTemplate ,
    className : 'time-selector-extra',
    onRender: function(){
        var context = this.model.toJSON();
        context.isnew = this.model.isNew();
        context.timezones = JSON.parse(Timezones.timezonesList);
    }
    .
    .
});
```

What I need now is to populate the option fields in my template during onRender as soon as I get the value of all the timezones list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the [serializeData](http://marionettejs.com/docs/current/marionette.itemview.html#itemview-serializedata) View method to populate your template with data coming from other sources than the current Model.

```
var TimeView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template : TimeTemplate ,
    className : 'time-selector-extra',
    serializeData: function(){
        var context = this.model.toJSON();
        context.isnew = this.model.isNew();
        context.timezones = JSON.parse(Timezones.timezonesList);
        return context;
    }
    .
    .
});
```

As this method overrides the default serialization (that just `return this.model.toJSON()`), make sure you do return an object to populate the template as wished.

If Timezones data aren't available at the time the view is rendered, you could `listenTo` an event on the Timezones object to re-render the view when data become available.

```
var TimeView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    initialize: function(){
            this.listenTo(Timezones, 'change', this.render)

    },
    ...
})
```

(I assume here that Timezones is an instance of Backbone.Model, would fire a `change` event)